# Python value error when running script from cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, cluster-computing

I'm trying to run a script in python from google cloud cluster.

The code works when I ran it in jupyter notebook but in the cluster I get an error.

This is the error I get

[image]

And this is the code that throws the error :

[image]

I think the problem is with reading the parquet files. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Apparently `li` is an empty list, so pandas complain that there is nothing to concatenate. You also don't see any output in the terminal from the `print` statement. Check that you have provided the correct file path to `glob`.

Comment: The path to the files is right. The problem is that the code works when I run it from jupyter notebook but doesn't run from the cloud cluster

Comment: if you run it on the cloud, the paths will become wrong because the cloud can't see the files on your computer

Comment: You should move your Parquet files to [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) and read directly to the bucket.